# How to get an image from a fragment inside a fragment?

Tags: java, android, image, fragment, startactivityforresult

I have a project organized as follows:

AdminAddNewMerchantActivity

->TimeFragment

---->FindFoodAdminFragment

---->MapMerchantFagment

---->PriceFragment

---->StartFragment

---->EndFragment

->OrdersFragment

---->IncompleteOrders

---->CompleteOrders

PickImageActivity

where:

-> - a new subdirectory

----> - a subsubdirectory

I'm trying to pick an image and assign it. I successfully got it to work in `PickImageActivity`, but have problems getting the same code to work from `FindFoodAdminFragment`. The code for `PickImageActivity` that I use is as follows:

```
public class PickImageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView image;
CircleImageView imageBanner;
private Uri imageUri, imageUri2;
private static final int GalleryPick = 1, GalleryPickBanner = 2;

   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pick_image);
   .
   .
   .
        image = findViewById(R.id.pi_input_merchant_image);
        imageBanner = findViewById(R.id.pi_input_banner_image);
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, 
        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GalleryPick);
   .
   .
   .
    }

   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
   {
           super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
           if((requestCode == GalleryPick) && (resultCode == RESULT_OK) && (data!=null))
           {
               imageUri = data.getData();
               image.setImageURI(imageUri);
               //  Prevalent.currentMerchant.setImage();
           }
           else if((requestCode == GalleryPickBanner) && (resultCode == RESULT_OK) && (data!=null))
           {
               imageUri2 = data.getData();
               imageBanner.setImageURI(imageUri2);
           }
       }
   }
}
```

The problem is in `startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GalleryPick);` I tried `super.startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GalleryPick);` and `getParentFragment().startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GalleryPick);` but it doesn't work. How do I get it to work from `FindFoodAdminFragment`?

Comment: In FindFoodAdminFragment, start the Activity using `getActivity().startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GalleryPick)`. You don't need a PickImageActivity just to launch an Intent. You can use the Parent activity of FindFoodAdminFragment using `getActivity()`

Comment: You shouldn't need to call the Activity startActivityForResult(...) method (e.g., getActivity().startActivityForResult(...) or super.startActivityForResult(...)). You should be able to call startActivityForResult directly from your Fragment.

Comment: When i try using getActivity().startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GalleryPick) in FindFoodAdminFragment, it loads a new activity which allows me to select the picture. when i select the picture, it does not return to the fragment or activity FindFoodAdminFragment/AdminAddNewMerchantActivity which it started from. It does not go to onActivityResult inside FindFoodAdminFragment. It goes to the activity before FindFoodAdminFragment/AdminAddNewMerchantActivity. I also tried startActivityForResult(...). I think that it fails somewhere inside there and closes the activity with all the fragments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by starting a new activity from FindFoodAdminFragment and using getIntent().getExtras() and intent.putExtra("myKey", myString) to transmit data between the activity and fragment. In an activity startActivityForResult works fine so I used it in the activity then onActivityResult activity is triggered. In onActivityResult i putExtra the imageUri, then I started another activity which contained FindFoodAminFragment and getExtras. Thanks for help all.